# Are laptops too un-ergonomic for desk job without a dock-screen-mouse setup?

Tags: new-job

New boss asked if I prefer laptop or desktop. On the one hand, I would say laptop for sure if I knew he'd buy a dock, monitor, mouse, etc. to make it ergonomically like a desktop in the office. I don't want to fork up that money myself and uncomfortable asking him to do it.

Assuming laptop-only (no add-ons) will be too hard for a full day at the desk, is it better to try to explain this to him or to go with desktop?

Comment: I edited this to make it more of a focus on ergonomics, which is on topic here. Questions like, "what should I choose/do" are not really on topic but ergonomics questions are. It seems the main thing you are asking is about the ergonomics, but feel free to [edit] if I changed your intent too much!

Comment: Voting to close, depends on what the poster is doing on the computer, how they work (do they need to go anywhere with it, take it into work each day etc), far too broad to answer

Comment: The question as unedited was more of how much I can push for this as a new hire. I don't think it's a pure ergonomic question, since if I was self-employed I would get a laptop with all the trappings I mentioned. But, do as you see fit.

Comment: For all practical purposes, if you take a laptop, and plug in a monitor, mouse and keyboard, then you've got a desktop.  Whether or not you need a docking station really depends on what else you need to connect.

Comment: @A.N. push for what? Do you mean how you can ask for a docking station and separate monitor if you choose a laptop?

Comment: @enderland To add a monitor, mouse etc. so it's like sitting at a desktop in the office.

Comment: Do you have to take computer with you for any reason work-related? Since you are talking about "a full day at the desk" that is unclear to me. If the answer is *no*, it's a no-brainer: take a fully equipped desktop (because the only advantage of a laptop is portability).

Comment: @Jan Doggen, my answer is it depends. (i) I haven't gotten an answer on whether I can take it home which would be a big plus, and he might have been hoping for a less complicated answer on my part since I am starting soon and need a computer. (ii) I will be spending a lot of time in other people's offices in training, so I will also be able to use it to take notes etc.

Comment: I am getting the drift that I am not understood, which may be because I am new here :-). Happy to delete the thread and to bother y'all with better questions another time.

Comment: It's not that you are not being understood, you seem to be needlessly complicating things. It is irrelevant that you feel *uncomfortable asking him to do*. Your boss asks you what you want. You answer the same you say in your question. He will either say yes or no. And you have several people here saying or implying that the docking station is unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you feel uncomfortable asking about docking station etc. ? All you have to say is "is that a laptop with a monitor, mouse and docking station, or without?" No need to ask your boss to buy them. His answer will be "yes", "no", or "I haven't thought about it. Do you think monitor etc. would be better?" and you go from there.

Comment: On a laptop with good touchpad you don't need a mouse. The mouse that I got for use with my MacBook has been in the drawer for all of its life. Your mileage may vary. And laptop + monitor can be better than desktop + monitor because you have two screens.

Comment: If you get a desktop computer he'll need to provide a monitor, keyboard, and mouse anyway, so does this come down to the dock?  Or are you worried that he wouldn't get the peripherals at all if you say laptop?  I'm sorry if this is frustrating; we do want to help you, and just need to make sure we understand the question.  Thanks and welcome!

Comment: I've been using a laptop as a desktop for many years, both my personal machine and at work. With a fast USB hub, a docking station is mostly unnecessary; the only advantage is that some docking stations support Yet Another external monitor. (And even those are often USB-attached these days.)

Comment: @keshlam: The advantage of a docking station, though, is that you can just insert & release the laptop with one press of a latch (at least with my Thinkpad one) instead of plugging & unplugging a bunch of cables.

Comment: With USB, "a bunch" may be two or three, which isn't that big a deal.. Even a complicated setuo like my personal machine --- two printers, scanner, barcode reader, 24-bit outboard audio, external keyboard, trackball,  wired network, ups, ... there are only four cables go the laptop, two usb hubs, video, ethernet and power.  That's pretty close to grab-and-go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are laptops too un-ergonomic for desk job without a dock-screen-mouse
>   setup?

Not for me.

I tend to carry the laptop to many meetings. I used to have a docking station but don't bother any more. It seems just fine to me.

But ergonomics aren't one-size-fits-all. Some folks like the portability of laptops, but hate the keyboard, for example. They may be willing to tolerate the limitations of the screen size for short durations, but prefer a large screen for extended viewing. Etc, etc.

If the thought of a laptop appeals to you, request it over a desktop. Then, after using it for a few months, ask for additional accessories only if needed.

Comment: I agree, I prefer a laptop, there is one thing I have noticed though. I find a laptop sufficient on it's own only if it has a decent screen size and a numeric keypad. But that might just be me.

Comment: Being older and having worked with computers for the last 35 years, ergonomics are a concern for me.  The youngsters, perhaps not as much.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  Yes, it does vary from person to person.  My mother needed surgery for her wrists by the time she was in her 40s

Comment: @Kilisi: Make that a properly-placed CURSOR keypad :-)  I've used a laptop for all my day-to-day work for a decade (serious number-crunching gets offloaded to other machines), with docking station, standard keyboard, and large high-res display.  It only gets used as a stand-alone laptop a few percent of the time, but it's awfully handy to have that capability.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking an either-or situation, there are other factors to be considered. For me, I'd be looking at how often I'll need the added functionality of the laptop (the ability to take it to meetings/site visits, etc.) over the issues of fixed keyboard, trackpad, and screen.

For me, being able to move my keyboard around my desk without throwing issues with the screen, and the ability to raise and lower the screen would do it for me. Plus the fact that a relatively small 17" monitor would be difficult to get on a laptop.

Comment: "Plus the fact that a relatively small 17" monitor would be difficult to get on a laptop." Difficult? Not at all, at least in the U.S. More expensive? Probably

Comment: That was kind of my point. 17" is about the minimum acceptable for desktop screen, but on the upper end of laptop specs. And we're talking about business cases here, more expensive = more difficult.

Comment: If that was your point, it wasn't very clear. In this circumstance, the cost difference shouldn't be a lot of money and shouldn't be a deciding factor; if it is, it's probably time to look for a new job because either the business is in trouble, or the boss is an extreme penny pincher.

Answer (score -1):

Yes a laptop is compromised in so many ways in terms of RSI and performance unless you are spending 70-80% of the time on the road out visiting clients a desk top is a much better choice (its also cheaper than the equivalent lap top set up).

Comment: All machines wait for user input at the same speed. Not everyone needs the highest possible performance. Some of the gaming laptops are also as fast as most desktops, though the tradeiff is short battery life when used in thag mode. Tools for tasks. Which is why I VTC -- this is either Opinion or Too Broad.

Comment: @keshlam there s no such thing as to much IPC , RAM and DASD  aside from he the RSI issue that laptops have.

Comment: There is no such thing as toomuch, agreed. That dkesn't mean anything less than the ultimate is not enough., however. And the option of mobility also has nontrivial value. There is not only one correct answer here.